# formatting bar charts pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How to show the entire bars and slightly extend the y axis in both directions (top and bottom)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            xmin = 0,
            y = 35pt,
            bar width= 2em,
            axis x line       = none,
            axis y line       = left,
            tickwidth         = 0pt,
            symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D},
            nodes near coords,
          ]
          \addplot coordinates { (45,A) (55,B) (40,C) (50,D) };
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can enlarge the y limits with `enlarge y limits`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            xmin = 0,
            y = 35pt,
            bar width= 2em,
            axis x line       = none,
            axis y line       = left,
            tickwidth         = 0pt,
            symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D},
            nodes near coords,enlarge y limits=0.2
          ]
          \addplot coordinates { (45,A) (55,B) (40,C) (50,D) };
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why if `enlarge y limits=0.2,` is inserted before, for example between `xmin = 0` and `y = 35pt`, this key doesn't have the expected effect? I don't find in the manual a such restriction.

Comment: @quark67 On p. 329 it is written that "Specifying a number value like ‘enlarge x limits=0.2’ will enlarge lower and upper axis limit rela- tively. The following example adds 20% of the axis limits on both sides:" and I think the analogous statement applies to `enlarge y limits`.

Comment: I speak about the position of the key *enlarge y limits*. You add it after *nodes near coords*. But if you move it between for example, *xmin = 0* and *y = 35pt*, it seems don’t have any effect (ie: it gave the same output as the OP screenshot). Is this behavior only on my installation?

Comment: Thank marmot. I tried this before, but as @quark67 said I was placing it just after y = 35pt and it was not working.